# Belisha Beacon Java Program button query

Tags: java, swing, flash, jframe

the task is to write code for a Belisha Beacon which starts off as flashing and the colours alternate between light grey and Orange and has two buttons which are Flash and Steady. So when I click the Steady button, the Beacon has to stay as Orange but for my program, the Beacon stays steady on whichever colour it was when I click on the Steady button and when I click on the Flash button after I have clicked on the Steady button, the Beacon doesn't flash again. Here is my code so far, someone please help me where I have gone wrong, thank you :).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BelishaBeacon {
    private static Timer timer;
    public class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;
        private boolean changeColors = false;


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            //creating the shapes
            Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);

            //drawing the shapes
            Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2.draw(ball);
            g2.draw(box1);
            g2.draw(box2);
            g2.draw(box3);
            g2.draw(box4);
            g2.draw(box5);
            g2.draw(box6);
            //coloring the shapes
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(box1);
            g2.fill(box3);
            g2.fill(box5);
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(ball);
            changeColors = !changeColors;
            if (changeColors) {
                g2.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
            }
        }




        public void changeColors() {
            changeColors = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public BelishaBeacon() {
        //Creation of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 570);
        frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                shapes.repaint();
            }
        });



        JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
        jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            }
        });




        final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                });

        //Positioning
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
        controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);

        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(shapes);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BelishaBeacon();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So for your Flash button, the listener is currently empty. What you want to do is to check that when the flash button is pressed then start the timer again.

Try this

```
JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
    jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Flashing");
            if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                timer.start();
            }

        }
    });
```

And for your Steady button problem. There is no logic there at the moment to check what is the current colour i.e. if it is Grey or Yellow. So you will need somehow modify the code to check the current colour state and stop it when it is Yellow. Have some thoughts :)

Comment: Thank you so much bili :), that helped me a lot :D.

Comment: @Federer have a go at the Steady button for now and check back here if you're still stuck then.

Comment: The Steady button I tried changing it to make sure it stays on Orange regardless of when I click the Steady button but still no luck. But it does start flashing again which is a good sing.

Comment: @Federer how can you tell with the current code whether the colour is Orange or Gray? Hint: have a look at code that paint the ball :)

Comment: Is it the setColor? :)

Comment: @Federer what have you tried? Maybe now is good time to update your post with your current code.